# What is the correct way to perform a one-way repeated measures ANOVA in R with unbalanced data

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, biostatistics

I have been researching how to do a repeated measures ANOVA in R for a few days, and the problem is there are so many different ways of doing it, that I do not know what the correct or best method is.

The data I want to analyze has one dependent variable (Prosomal Width), and one independent variable (Location) that consists of 3 different locations (ML,MP,NWC). My design is unbalanced because I found most of my horseshoe crabs in ML, very few in MP, and only one in NWC. Basically, what I want to know is if prosomal width differs between these 3 areas.

Here is the beginning of my data, which I believe is in the correct format??
[image]

Also, do I test for the assumptions of ANOVA before of after I build the model?

Comment: This may be a useful guide: https://ww2.coastal.edu/kingw/statistics/R-tutorials/unbalanced.html

Comment: For a one way anova, unbalanced data sets aren't a big deal (think about it as in a t-test situation).